# using OneHotEncoder with sklearn_pandas DataFrameMapper

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sklearn_pandas DataFrameMapper. This takes in the column names along with the preprocessing Transformation function that is required for that column. Like so,

```
mapper = sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([
    ('hour',None),
    ('season',sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()),
    ('holiday',None)
])
```

season is an int64 col in my pandas DataFrame.

This gives me the following error - Too many values to unpack. 
I understand that OneHotEncoder takes a 2-D sample and not a 1-D sample.

How do i get to use this OneHotEncoder with sklearn_pandas or is it not possible.

Comment: Can you give a stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official version of `sklearn-pandas` have some problems when dealing with one-dimensional arrays and transformations. Try the following fork:
https://github.com/dukebody/sklearn-pandas

However, I think you can accomplish what you want using `LabelBinarizer` (as in the `sklearn_pandas` examples) instead of `OneHotEncoder`.

**UPDATE 2015-11-28**

In `sklearn-pandas>=0.0.12` you can solve your problem doing the following:

```
mapper = sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([
    ('hour',None),
    (['season'],sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()),
    ('holiday',None)
])
```

From the docs:

> The difference between specifying the column selector as `'column'` (as
>   a simple string) and `['column']` (as a list with one element) is the
>   shape of the array that is passed to the transformer. In the first
>   case, a one dimensional array with be passed, while in the second case
>   it will be a 2-dimensional array with one column, i.e. a column
>   vector.