# sklearn_pandas DataFrameMapper messing up OneHotEncoder column names

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.preprocessing
import sklearn_pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({'z': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']})

sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([
    (['z'], sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(drop='first'))
], df_out=True).fit_transform(df)
```

outputs

```
   z_x0_b  z_x0_c
0     0.0     0.0
1     1.0     0.0
2     1.0     0.0
3     0.0     1.0
```

Why are the column names messed up? I don't want `x0` in there.

Related

- [using OneHotEncoder with sklearn_pandas DataFrameMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010853/using-onehotencoder-with-sklearn-pandas-dataframemapper)
- [How to output Pandas object from sklearn pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150352/how-to-output-pandas-object-from-sklearn-pipeline)

Comment: `df.z.str.get_dummies()` ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem, I'd generally like to separate fit & transform

Comment: @YOBEN_S `get_dummies()` is *never* a good choice because it doesn't preserve inverse transforms.

Comment: Why are you using DataFrameMapper? For just one column, you can directly use OneHotEncoder.
sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(drop='first', sparse=False).fit_transform(df)

However, if you want to apply different transformations/Encoders/Scalar/Imputers, then you can use DataFrameMapper.

Another option is to use ColumnTransformer

Comment: @DrNishaArora, it's not one column, just in this example